# Find out id of track or use permalink to stream track?

Tags: android, ios, api, streaming, soundcloud

we want to use soundcloud to stream short sound snippets in our Android and iOS apps.

1. we upload a track
2. we get the permalink
3. we want to use it as the URL to stream the sound inside our app

Should we only add `/stream` to the url or how we get to know the id and so the streaming url?

example sound
http://soundcloud.com/sebastian-kurt/audio-recording-on-friday/
how to find out streaming url?

Thanks, Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read the SoundCloud API Documentation, notably http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks

The response from API calls to /tracks give you a `streamable` & `stream_url` for the track.

Comment: I have read it and maybe my question was not exactly enough. As I am only given the permalink, which does not have an id (integer), I need to know where get the id for the track behind it.

Comment: That's cool - use /resolve to get the API info for a permalink. 

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve

Comment: is there a way without API?

Comment: Not that I know of, the API seems easy enough to use.